# Usage of Ambivalence

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

> Ambivalence surged within me.

Or

> I felt ambivalent.

Those do not sound right to me. I am trying to describe the feeling where my boss rejects an idea that I have worked so hard for - I have mixed feelings because I do want this project I have spent so much of my time on to be implemented, however, my boss's point is valid to a certain degree.

I started off with "I had mixed feelings," but was wondering if there was a better way to put it (both more accurate and more sophisticated).

Comment: *Ambivalence* is the right word, for having mixed feelings. But I am not sure *ambivalence* is something that *surges*. It suggests hesitation and indecision.

Comment: Echoing @WS2 - the most active verb that I would use with ambivalence might be `ambivalence seeped into me`; but I'd usually described ambivalence as a condition (`I was suffocated by ambivalence`), not as an independent thing.

Comment: I'm ambivalent about saying that "ambivalence surged".  I would think it "sloshed" or some such, being much less precisely defined.

Comment: What's the question? Those don't sound right to you. And? If your question is "*What's a better way to put it?*" then (1) you need to specify more clearly what "*it*" is and (2) you need to define your criteria for "*better way*". And if that's the question then it seems anyway primarily opinion-based or asking for proofreading, both of which are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Both "I felt ambivalent" and "I had mixed feelings" are effective ways of expressing how you felt.  There's a third option, which isn't necessarily better, or more sophisticated:

> I was of two minds.

which is especially good when you're having trouble making a decision.

If you're just basically confused about how you feel about something, you can say

> I wasn't sure how I felt about it.  [On the one hand, bla bla, on the other hand, etc.]